# Should I use an enum with lots of fields or a class with lots of methods

Tags: java, performance, enums

I am tasked with testing several versions of a RestAPI. I thought of two ways to contain the set of valid rest calls.  In the first case, I would have RestUrlFactory which contains a method that corresponds to each rest call.  For example, I would have the methods:

```
public RestURL Version_1_1_PRODUCTS_GET();
public RestURL Version_1_1_PRODUCTS_PUT();
public RestURL Version_1_2_PRODUCTS_PRODUCT(int productId);
...etc
```

Alternatively, I figured I can have the RestUrlFactory contain an enumeration for
each API Version. In which case, I would have an enum field for each rest call.

```
enum Version_1_1 implements RestUrl
{
    PRODUCTS_GET("/products", "GET"),
    PRODUCTS_PUT("TestProduct", "PUT"),
    ...
}
```

Or something of that nature.  I think the latter option (using enums) is much cleaner. However, my question is if it is also good OOP Practice, and is it better in terms of performance?  I figure using enumerations will result in the factory class taking up much less space.

Comment: Use what you find the cleaner, and optimize if, and where needed. Performance is irrelevant here, especially if you're going to make HTTP requests, which are going to be many orders of magnitude slower than accessing a field in an enum (like nanoseconds vs. seconds).

Comment: Premature optimization, we meet again... Now seriously, no use in having code you can barely read or mantain just because it has a fancy name like "principle" or "pattern". Go for the approach you get along the best, use your brain to keep it usable (don't run blindly behind a concept but apply good practices) and then tune it up whenever you need it, not before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If people consuming this API are going to be making calls over HTTP, that is going to vastly outweigh any performance considerations here. Don't worry about performance: that will be premature optimization.

Using method signatures seems to me like it would give users the easiest API to use, since it provides type-safety and a very specific argument signature. I'd go with that.